# Exclude service accounts from the people finder (search)

Tags: 2013, search-results, people-search

I have a People Finder page which uses the Search Results webpart, I'm wanting to exclude all service accounts from the search results, how can I achieve this without manually inputting all the accounts into the search query ({searchboxquery} -0182 –SA0092 –SA0036 etc).

*I'm not very experienced with search, so you may have to simplify your answer slightly.

Comment: Are these service accounts in a dedicated OU of the AD? Also: do they have a common property the norml user accounts don't? e.g. they don't have an email address, while all users do have one.

Comment: Active Directory

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have this information as it's for a client, we don't have access to their AD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My colleague and I found a solution to our problem:

In the 'Search Results' webpart > 'Change Query' > in the 'Query Text' box add {searchboxquery} -Firstname="0*" -Firstname="SA0*"> OK

*Our service accounts all began with a 0 or SA0.